# Why does computing L2 norm with cuBLAS result in an error?

Tags: cuda, thrust, gpu, cublas

**Edit 2:** include the more full program

**Edit 1:** include the full program

I'm trying to compute the L2 norm of a vector using cuBLAS. My code is as follows

```
void GPU_Print_Matrix(real_t *A, int nrows, int ncols) {
  real_t *hostA = (real_t*)malloc(nrows*ncols * sizeof(real_t));
  CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostA, A, nrows*ncols * sizeof(real_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  cout << "GPU Matrix of Size: " << nrows << "x" << ncols << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
      cout << fixed << setprecision(PRINT_PRECISION) << hostA[j*nrows + i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  free(hostA);
  cout << endl;
}

void GPU_Random_Vector(thrust::device_vector <real_t> &vec) {
  thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned int> index_sequence_begin(rand());
  thrust::transform(index_sequence_begin, index_sequence_begin + vec.size(), vec.begin(), RANDOM(-initRange, initRange));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  srand(clock());
  cout << "# Running NMT" << endl;

  //ParseOpts(argc, argv);

  cublasHandle_t handle;
  CUBLAS_SAFE_CALL(cublasCreate(&handle));
  thrust::device_vector <real_t> x(10);
  GPU_Random_Vector(x);
  GPU_Print_Matrix(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&x[0]), 10, 1);
  real_t nrm = 0; 
  CUBLAS_SAFE_CALL(cublasXnrm2(handle, 10, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&x[0]), 1, &nrm));
  cout << "nrm2 = " << nrm << endl;
}
```

Here, `CUBLAS_SAFE_CALL` is defined as follows

```
#define CUBLAS_SAFE_CALL(call)                                                     \
{                                                                                  \
  const cublasStatus_t stat = call;                                                \
  if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {                                             \
    cout << "cuBlas Error: " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << endl;               \
    cout << "  Code: " << stat << endl;                                            \
    exit(1);                                                                       \
  }                                                                                \
}
```

`GPU_Random_Vector` and `GPU_Print_Matrix` have been confirmed to work before. Also, `cublasHandle[singleGPU]` has been initialized before being called. When I ran the program, I had the following output

```
// GPU_Print_Matrix
GPU Matrix of Size: 10x1
0.0652332678 
0.0747700930 
0.0274266358 
-0.0885794610 
-0.0192640368 
-0.0942506194 
0.0283640027 
-0.0411146656 
-0.0460337885 
-0.0970785618 

cuBlas Error: nmt.cu:2252
  Code: 14
```

What is going on? And is there any reference for how can I interpret the error number of cuBLAS? Thanks a ton.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the full program.

Comment: @HieuPham: Sorry, but that isn't the full program. What are `GPU_Random_Vector`  and `GPU_Print_Matrix` ?

Comment: This code is still incomplete and uncompilable. It is not possible to provide and answer to your question until you can provide code which reproduces your problem.

Comment: So what ever happened here? You added and deleted a comment on my answer before I could read it over a year ago, but what was the conclusion? Were you able to reproduce the problem you had using the code I posted? Did you eventually locate the source of the problem in your own code? Is there an answer to be added or accepted here? Or should this question just be deleted?

Answer (score 2):

CUBLAS error 14 is `CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR` and would usually mean that the internal device to host copy at the end of the L2 norm call failed. But why that happened is impossible to say without some context about what else your code was doing.

If the code you posted is assembled and fleshed out into a complete demo case (with the trivial random number seeding mistake correct) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>

typedef float real_t;

#define CUBLAS_SAFE_CALL(call)                                                     \
{                                                                                  \
  const cublasStatus_t stat = call;                                                \
  if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {                                             \
    std::cout << "cuBlas Error: " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;     \
    std::cout << "  Code: " << stat << std::endl;                                  \
    exit(1);                                                                       \
  }                                                                                \
}

#define PRINT_PRECISION (6)

struct RANDOM
{
    real_t a, b;

    __host__ __device__
    RANDOM(real_t _a=0, real_t _b=1) : a(_a), b(_b) {};

    __host__ __device__
        real_t operator()(const unsigned int n) const
        {
            thrust::default_random_engine rng;
            thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(a, b);
            rng.discard(n);

            return dist(rng);
        }
};

void GPU_Print_Matrix(real_t *A, int nrows, int ncols) {
  real_t *hostA = (real_t*)malloc(nrows*ncols * sizeof(real_t));
  cudaMemcpy(hostA, A, nrows*ncols * sizeof(real_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  std::cout << "GPU Matrix of Size: " << nrows << "x" << ncols << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
      std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(PRINT_PRECISION) << hostA[j*nrows + i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  free(hostA);
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void GPU_Random_Vector(thrust::device_vector <real_t> &vec) {
  const real_t initRange = 10;
  thrust::counting_iterator<unsigned int> index_sequence_begin(std::rand());
  thrust::transform(index_sequence_begin, index_sequence_begin + vec.size(), vec.begin(), RANDOM(-initRange, initRange));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::srand(std::time(0));
  std::cout << "# Running NMT" << std::endl;

  cublasHandle_t handle;
  CUBLAS_SAFE_CALL(cublasCreate(&handle));
  thrust::device_vector <real_t> x(10);
  GPU_Random_Vector(x);
  GPU_Print_Matrix(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&x[0]), 10, 1);
  real_t nrm = 0; 
  CUBLAS_SAFE_CALL(cublasSnrm2(handle, 10, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&x[0]), 1, &nrm));
  std::cout << "nrm2 = " << nrm << std::endl;
}
```

and compiled and run like this (CUDA 6.5 if that matters):

```
>nvcc -arch=sm_21 -run runkkari.cu -lcublas
runkkari.cu
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp
# Running NMT
GPU Matrix of Size: 10x1
-5.712992
8.181723
-0.086308
-6.177320
-5.442665
-2.889552
-1.555665
6.506872
-6.800190
8.024273

nrm2 = 18.196394
```

It works as expected. You should be able to compile and run this to confirm this yourself. So from this we can only conclude that you have another problem which you have failed to describe. But perhaps this helps to narrow down the list of possibilities.